# how can i calculate the percentage between the values ​of these two queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am working on postgres and i have these two queries:

```
SELECT "Name", COUNT("xx")
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON "IDtable1" = "IDtable2"
WHERE "xx" = True
GROUP BY "Name"


SELECT "Name", COUNT("xx")
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON "IDtable1" = "IDtable2"
GROUP BY "Name"
```

how do i calculate the percentage between the results of these two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is to use `avg()`:

```
SELECT "Name", AVG("xx"::int)
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON "IDtable1" = "IDtable2"
GROUP BY "Name";
```

Or conditional aggregation:

```
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "xx") * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
```

Comment: After that I should multiply by one hundred, right?

Comment: @EpicBrozo96 . . . If you want a value between 0 and 100.